# jQuery loop through first x items in array of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

This code loops through an array of check boxes and collects the checked items to populate another input on the same form:

```
$("input[id^='checkbox1']").change(function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        title.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        var i = title.indexOf($(this).val());
        if(i != -1) title.splice(i,1);
    }
        $('#input1').val(title.join(", "));
    });
```

How do I limit the collection of array items to items 0,1,3,4,6 and 7 (or, alternatively, exclude items 2, 5 and 8)?

Comment: I don't see where you are "looping" here, you are binding to `.change`. Did you mean to use `.each`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `loop` but I have create a code and fiddle to create this type of series,
it may help you,

```
var j=0;
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(j>2)
    {
        j=0;
    }
    if(j<=1)
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
    j++;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3tBw/)

Comment: I ended up excluding the array items based on the values in them, which was really what I was going for anyway.
    if(newTitle !== "exclval1" && newTitle !== "exclval2" && newTitle !== "exclval3")